# list index is out of range - cannot find why

Tags: python

I'm writing code to sort data into lists and then arrange these lists, but I keep getting:

> builtins.IndexError: list index out of range

The data in the code is:

```
Class 1: 
Matthew 5   5   1
Paul    9   3   6
Sara    9   4   2
Nicholas3   2   4
Larry   5   2   5
Philip  4   4   6
Patricia7   7   7
Gary    0   9   4
Marie   8   7   1
Scott   4   3   2

Class 2: 
Heather 10  2   3
Lawrence 2  4   4
Stephen 1   6   8
Robert  3   5   4
Shawn   9   6   6
Michelle 6  7   4
Chris   10  4   2
Teresa  5   5   6
Dennis  7   8   1
Rose    8   3   4

Class 3:
Jojo    10  3   9
Sarah   1   2   8
Jerry   5   3   7
Aaron   7   8   5
Carl    3   7   5
Christine   9   4   4
Jennifer    2   8   2
Linda   8   8   1
Justin  4   6   3
Emily   2   4   7
```

The code:

```
import csv

while True:
    ClassNumber = int(input("What class would you like to see the results for?"))
    if 1<= ClassNumber <=3:
        break
    print("That class does not exist. Please choose from 1,2 or 3")

if ClassNumber == 1:
    ClassFile = "class1scores.csv"
elif ClassNumber == 2:
    ClassFile = "class2scores.csv"
else:
    ClassFile = "class3scores.csv"

OpenFile = open(ClassFile, "r")
scores = csv.reader(OpenFile)    

newlist = []

for row in scores:
    row[1] = int(row[1])
    row[2] = int(row[2])
    row[3] = int(row[3]) 

    HighestScore = max(row[0:3])
    row.append(HighestScore)

    AverageScore = round(sum(row[0:3])/3)
    row.append(AverageScore)
```

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: @chepner Exactly...!

Comment: Not the source of your problem, but shouldn't `max(row[0:3])` be `max(row[1:4])` and the same with avarage score?

Comment: Please fix your indentation in the post. Python indentation is syntactically significant, and as posted, this is not valid code.

Answer (score 4):

By default, `csv.reader` assumes that a comma is the field delimiter, but your data is tab-delimited. As a result, each row has only one item, not four.

```
scores = csv.reader(OpenFile, delimiter="\t")
```

Comment: I see your point, but the 'builtins.IndexError: list index out of range' is still appearing and I have no idea why :/

Comment: Do you actually have tabs separating each field? You appear to have a row which does not actually have 4 tab-separated fields, so as a result `row[3]` raises the error you are seeing. That's why I asked which line actually raises the error.